# How to resolve type mismatch when mapping results using scalikeJDBC?

Tags: scala, types, scalikejdbc

I typed a couple of lines on [Single / Optional Result for Query @ ScalikeJDBC Docs](http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/operations.html):

```
package org.mysample

import scalikejdbc._

// define a class to map the result
case class Emp(id: String, name: String)

// QueryDSL
object Emp extends SQLSyntaxSupport[Emp] {
  def apply(e: ResultName[Emp])(rs: WrappedResultSet): Emp =
    new Emp(id = rs.get(e.id), name = rs.get(e.name))
}

class TestClass {
  val emp: Option[Emp] = DB readOnly { implicit session =>
    sql"SELECT id, name FROM emp WHERE id = ${id}"
      .map(rs => Emp(rs.string("id"), rs.string("name"))).single.apply()
  }

  val e = Emp.syntax("e")
  val id = 123
  val emp2: Option[Emp] = DB readOnly { implicit session =>
    withSQL {
      select.from(Emp as e).where.eq(e.id, id)
    }.map(Emp(e)).single.apply()
  }
}
```

But this snippet has an compile error:

```
[error] /Users/pj/git/sirloin/src/main/scala/org/mysample/emp.scala:25: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scalikejdbc.QuerySQLSyntaxProvider[scalikejdbc.SQLSyntaxSupport[org.mysample.Emp],org.mysample.Emp]
[error]  required: scalikejdbc.ResultName[org.mysample.Emp]
[error]     (which expands to)  scalikejdbc.ResultNameSQLSyntaxProvider[scalikejdbc.SQLSyntaxSupport[org.mysample.Emp],org.mysample.Emp]
[error]     }.map(Emp(e)).single.apply()
[error]               ^
```

I cleaned and recompiled in sbt, but still failed to compile. What is wrong with this code?

Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for bothering you. Just specify `map(Emp(e.resultName))` instead. or update Emp companion object like this:

```
object Emp extends SQLSyntaxSupport[Emp] {
  def apply(e: ResultName[Emp])(rs: WrappedResultSet): Emp =
    new Emp(id = rs.get(e.id), name = rs.get(e.name))
  def apply(e: SyntaxProvider[Emp])(rs: WrappedResultSet): Emp = apply(e.resultName)(rs)
}
```

Comment: I'll fix the documentation.